# neighborlist.getCid() returns -1 as value always

Tags: android

I have used the following code,

```
 TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);


    List<NeighboringCellInfo> neighboringCellInfoList = telephonyManager.getNeighboringCellInfo();

    if (neighboringCellInfoList == null || neighboringCellInfoList.size() == 0)
    {

        /*Toast.makeText(this, "List Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
        Log.e(TAG, "List Empty");
    } else
    {
        TowerAdapter towerAdapter = new TowerAdapter(MainActivity.this, neighboringCellInfoList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(towerAdapter);

    }

}
```

And my bind view holder in adapter is

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TowerViewHolder towerViewHolder, int i) {

    String cid = String.valueOf(cellInfoList.get(i).getCid());

    String signal = String.valueOf(cellInfoList.get(i).getRssi());

    towerViewHolder.cid.setText(cid);
    towerViewHolder.signal.setText(signal);

}
```

But always I am getting '-1' as CID value.

what might me the problem?
[output screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgPAF.jpg)

Comment: Hi, @partha. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review your code, there is no `neighborlist.getCid()` anywhere in your code. Spotting these mistakes and fixing them would help you get solutions faster. Don't make potential helpers guess what you mean.

Comment: Note that `getNeighboringCellInfo()` was deprecated in api 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might just be the correct result instead of a problem.

For `NeighboringCellInfo` the method `getCid()` returns the value of UNKNOWN_CID if the network type is UMTS, CDMA, or Unknown.

The value of UNKNOWN_CID is -1.